# Is 'aren't you' right in the dialog in this movie?

Tags: grammar

I like the movie 'nikita' by the director, luc besson.
In the movie, this dialog comes at the end of the movie.

"You leave, aren't you"

I think that "don't you" is right.
Why do they use " aren't you " here?
Is there any grammar I don't know?

Comment: I thought Nikita was a French film, is this text from the subtitles?  It doesn't appear in one transcript http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/l/la-femme-nikita-script-transcript.html

Comment: *You're leaving, aren't you?*  *You are leaving, are you not?* *It's time, isn't it?* *It is time, is it not?*

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to an English dub of the movie? The final dialogue is in French, as is the rest of the movie, as far as I can tell.
"You leave, aren't you" is incorrect in any context. Correct versions would be

> You're leaving, aren't you?
>
> You want to leave, don't you?

Assuming the tense is supposed to be present progressive (someone is in the process of leaving), the first option is correct. If the tense is supposed to be present (describing what the person is right now), the second option is correct.

Comment: Good answer.  I think it is just about possible to imagine "You leave, don't you?" if the sense is along the lines of "You always leave, don't you?".